# Flash Builder 4.7 (Eclipse) - Settings crash

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

Everytime I exit Flash Builder 4.7, the next time I open it it tries to load settings but then crashes and generates a log. If I try to open FB again, it loads but all of my projects and tabs are closed. The log tells me it's trying to load a UI element, but can't so it clears my previous workspace. Here is the log output file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2016-10-21 14:23:36.917
!MESSAGE The URL "bundleentry://501.fwk104739310/icons/full/dlcl16/refresh.gif" could not be extracted probably due to insufficient permissions or insufficient disk space.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: The URL "bundleentry://501.fwk104739310/icons/full/dlcl16/refresh.gif" could not be extracted probably due to insufficient permissions or insufficient disk space.
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.URLConverterImpl.toFileURL(URLConverterImpl.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createResource(ImageDescriptor.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.DeviceResourceManager.allocate(DeviceResourceManager.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.AbstractResourceManager.create(AbstractResourceManager.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.LocalResourceManager.allocate(LocalResourceManager.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.AbstractResourceManager.create(AbstractResourceManager.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ResourceManager.createImageWithDefault(ResourceManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.updateImages(ActionContributionItem.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.update(ActionContributionItem.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.fill(ActionContributionItem.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewPane.updateActionBars(ViewPane.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewActionBars.updateActionBars(ViewActionBars.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.search2.internal.ui.SearchView.initializeToolBar(SearchView.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.search2.internal.ui.SearchView.createPartControl(SearchView.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.showView(Perspective.java:2245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1145)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$20.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:3918)
    at org.eclipse.search2.internal.ui.SearchViewManager.activateSearchView(SearchViewManager.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.search2.internal.ui.InternalSearchUI.runSearchInBackground(InternalSearchUI.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.search.ui.NewSearchUI.runQueryInBackground(NewSearchUI.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.search.ui.NewSearchUI.runQueryInBackground(NewSearchUI.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.text.TextSearchPage.performAction(TextSearchPage.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.SearchDialog.performAction(SearchDialog.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.util.ExtendedDialogWindow.buttonPressed(ExtendedDialogWindow.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4128)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3974)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3613)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.OpenSearchDialogAction.run(OpenSearchDialogAction.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.OpenSearchDialogAction.run(OpenSearchDialogAction.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.OpenSearchDialogPageAction.run(OpenSearchDialogPageAction.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4128)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3974)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3613)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.FlashBuilderApplication.start(FlashBuilderApplication.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Somtimes it also complains about these file paths, among others:
`bundleentry://501.fwk104739310/icons/full/dlcl16/stop.gif`
`bundleentry://501.fwk104739310/icons/full/dlcl16/pin_view.gif`
`bundleentry://501.fwk104739310/icons/full/dlcl16/search_history.gif`
Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure its not an 'insufficient permissions' issue, did u try running FB in admin mode?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion raksmen. I've just decided to drop FB and go towards IDEA. Theres just too many other problems that have come up and its not aging well.